# Switch IP's in browser

Tags: macos, vagrant, development-environment

For my development environment I'm looking for a way to change/override IP addresses used in DNS lookup for a domain, so I can point the domain to my local vagrant box with ease and without changing the hostfile everytime I want to switch back and forth from the live env to the dev env. I couldn't find a way to do this so I'm hoping there is a solution for this. I'm using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Vagrant Hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) plugin can be of help. It automatically adds entries to your local hosts file, when you include the following config in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.3.10"
config.vm.hostname = "www.testing.de"
config.hostsupdater.aliases = ["alias.testing.de", "alias2.somedomain.com"]
```

[Source](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater#usage)